# How to mock react-native-copilot?

Tags: react-native, jestjs, mocking, react-native-testing-library

Trying to mock with jest `react-native-copilot`

This is the point in the screen where the module is imported.

```
import { walkthroughable, CopilotStep } from 'react-native-copilot';
...
const CopilotText = walkthroughable(Text);
...
<View>
  <CopilotStep order={2} name='name'>
    <CopilotText testID={'test-schedule-name'}>
      {this.props.scheduleName}
    </CopilotText>
  </CopilotStep>
</View>
...
```

This is how it's mock it so far in the test:

```
jest.mock('react-native-copilot', () => ({
  getCurrentStep: jest.fn(() => { }),
}));
```

This is the test:

```
it('displays name', () => {
    const { getByTestId } = render(<MyComponent />);
    const scheduleName = getByTestId('test-schedule-name'); // it doesn't get this... why? 
    ...
});
```

This is the error:

```
Unable to find an element with testID: test-schedule-name
...
const CopilotText = walkthroughable(Text);
                    ^
```

Any idea?

Comment: Where is the error stack? Where does `walkthroughable` come from?

Comment: @slideshowp2 I've added more infos, I hope it's more clear now.

Comment: You're only showing the line where the error happens, but what's the actual error?

Comment: @juliomalves you're right. I've edited it, thx. Basically it doesn't find the testID:  `Unable to find an element with testID: test-schedule-name`